# Is <!--// //--> needed in javascript anymore? What was it used for?

Tags: javascript

Is  needed in javascript anymore? What was it used for?

Thanks

Comment: Not since Mosaic or something like that `:)`

Comment: oh sure, everyone falls over themselves to support IE6, but you're willing to just abandon NCSA Mosaic support?

Comment: @Wooble It would be interesting to see how today's web-sites render in Mosaic `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not needed any more. It was used to hide Javascript in old old browsers that didn't understand the `<script>` tag. Every browser made since the mid 90s understands Javascript, even if it doesn't support it for some reason. It would be `//<!--` and `//-->`. The leading `//` comments that line for browsers that understand Javascript. Browsers that don't understand Javascript would see the body of the script tag wrapped in an HTML comment (`<!--` `-->`), so they still wouldn't render it as if it was plain text.

Answer (score 4):

It was only needed for Netscape 1 and Mosaic.

[From Douglas Crockford:](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html)

> Do not use the `<!-- //-->` hack with
>   scripts. It was intended to prevent
>   scripts from showing up as text on the
>   first generation browsers Netscape 1
>   and Mosaic.

It hasn't been needed...basically ever.

Comment: And IE1 and IE2 I guess (since those didn't have scripting either).

Comment: Html dictates that any unrecognized tags be ignored. Mozilla and Netscape didn't properly ignore the tags; but instead rendered the content. The comments was a hack to work around a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is used to ensure that browsers that don't understand javascript won't show it as text. A super old browser will render

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var something = 0;
</script>
```

Just like a modern browser would render

```
<span>
    var something = 0;
</span>
```

Which, of course, is rendered as text. The comments at the beginning/end tell the browser to treat the contents as an HTML comment. Modern browsers know to ignore those.